Is it UB to use `delete` on a `int[1]` pointer?
I've encountered a situation in C++ that I find somewhat confusing and I'm seeking clarity:
int *p = new int[1];

In this case, p points to an array of length 1. I'm wondering if it's safe to use delete p; to deallocate this pointer, treating it as if it were a single variable, or if I must use delete[] p; to properly deallocate the memory.
I've tested this on my laptop, and delete p; seems to work fine, but I'm concerned about the possibility of undefined behavior. Could someone please point me to an official document or standard that confirms whether this is indeed undefined behavior or if it's acceptable practice?

Side note this is not how you should use (current) C++ in the first place. Dynamic memory allocation for arrays should use std::vector. The whole point being that using std::vector will avoid memory (de)allocation problems

From delete expression regarding delete ptr: "If ptr is anything else, including if it is a pointer obtained by the array form of new-expression, the behavior is undefined.". - i.e. delete p in your case is UB.

Working fine is one possible result of undefined behaviour. This is logical and consistent with the common meaning of undefined, but some beginners have trouble believing it. Bad programs don't always produce bad results, this is the reality of C++ programming.

I concur with @john, "seems to work" is just not good enough in C++. That's also why it is recommended to write unit tests (and even they will not catch everything).

This is a case of "happens to work" (at least on some compilers). If you have a type without a destructor (like int), the actual code generated for delete and delete[] might be the same, by chance. (Still UB though).

Also always compile with ALL warnings enabled see  : https://godbolt.org/z/5EToG7eno. The fact that you allocate only 1 integer this way doesn't affect the way you have to delete it. You still need delete[]

"Undefined behavior" means only that the C++ standard doesn't impose any requirement on what the code will do. It does not mean that bad things must happen.

new[] goes with delete[].  new goes with delete.  malloc goes with free.  They are not interchangeable.

or if I must use delete[] p -- Consider this: void foo(unsigned int n) { int *p = new int [n]; ... } -- To deallocate the memory, would you write if (n == 1) delete p; else delete [] p; }?  No.  You would simply delete [] p;, regardless of what n is.
